# Converting ImageJ ROI to R spatstat data doesn't work

Tags: r, image-processing, imagej, spatstat

I tried to use the `RImageJROI` package from David C Sterratt to transfer multiple `ROIs` into R and convert them to `Spatstat`.

This is a minimal example of my R-code

```
library(RImageJROI)
ROI = read.ijzip("path/ROI.zip")
spat.ROI = ij2spatstat(ROI)
```

Reading the zip-file works well but when I run the converting command I get the following error:

> Error in conv.fun(k, window = window, unitname = unitname, scale =
>   scale,  :    object 'out' not found

Attached there is a file for creating a `ROI.zip` -file which causes the error after processing it in `ImageJ` with:

```
    run("Analyze Particles...", "add");
roiManager("Save", "Path\\Roi.zip");
```

[image: Simple picture producing 2 ROIs]

Is there a way to get `RImageJROI` working, am I missing something obvious, or does anyone know another solution for my project?

Comment: Does `summary(ROI)`, `plot(ROI)` etc. work after you have read in the zip file? What kind of regions do you have (i.e. output of `sapply(ROI, function(x) x$strType)`)? Can you make your example reproducible without the need for ImageJ? Maybe just a link to the zip file?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Renjin script language](http://imagej.net/Renjin_Scripting), available with Fiji? It seems there is [partial support for spatstat](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/spatstat/). This script language can be used with [script parameters](https://imagej.net/Script_Parameters). Another option to try would be [Bio7](https://imagej.net/Bio7), which provides some ImageJ/R integration features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bio7](http://bio7.org) for that with has special methods to transfer different ImageJ ROI's and image data to R.

Some methods where especially designed for spatstat after a great spatstat tutorial on the [R conference in 2015](http://spatstat.org/useR2015/).

Here a link to some ImageJ spatstat notes and simple scripts:

http://bio7.org/?p=2618

https://github.com/Bio7/Bio7_Workshop

Here some video tutorials to transfer ROI data:

3D Point Pattern:
https://youtu.be/DmfSASgJa_g

Line Segments:
https://youtu.be/EPan7kibYpo

Polygons:
https://youtu.be/bS_2ejOt7Tg

Point Patterns:
https://youtu.be/7t5V2o8jFJw

Particle Measurments:
https://youtu.be/7t5V2o8jFJw

Georeferenced Polygons (which can be converted to spatstat objects):

https://youtu.be/P2NflfBB2Tg

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. I found this to work after looking inside the `ij2spatstat` function.

```
library(RImageJROI)
library(spatstat)

roi <- read.ijroi("RoiSet/0071-0081.roi") # path to single ROI
poly <- list(x = roi$coords[,2], y = roi$coords[,1])
out <- owin(poly = poly)

plot(out)
```

You can put this inside a loop to transform every ROI in a directory.

Comment: Update: I'm getting the error message "Area of polygon is negative - maybe traversed in wrong direction?" for some ROIs. This can be fixed by switching the column indices in the coordinates... still figuring out a workaround